# Is it possible to use the GoPro camera when it is connected to a pc/notebook with a USB Cable?

Tags: usb, gopro, gopro-wifi

I have Hero3+ Black Edition.

For now I cannot shoot or even configure the camera when it is connected to a notebook with 
a USB Cable.

When I connect my camera to a notebook with a USB Cable, a charging battery icon and a USB icon appear on a camera screen. Both buttons do nothing, are inactive (Shutter/Select Button and Power/Mode Button). Only Wi-Fi On/Off Button works. In addition, it is not possible to configure the camera with GoPro phone app – setting icons are disabled. Moreover, the phone app does not even show a current picture from the camera when the camera is connected with USB Cable (I use GoPro Android app on Google Nexus 5).

**My Question Is**: is it possible to use a camera when it is connected to PC/notebook with a USB cable? Is it somewhere configurable in the camera?

**My Goal Is**: I want to shoot and immediately see the result on a screen of my notebook. At least from MicroSD card. For now I make a picture or video, turn the camera off, take out MicroSD card, put it into a notebook and only now have a possibility to see the result. It is cumbersome.

Comment: This question shows lack of research or effort. I am not familiar with GoPro cameras and was able to find this on their site with little effort: "[You cannot record while the camera is connected to a computer.](http://gopro.com/support/articles/using-the-camera-while-charging)"

Comment: Find me info if it is possible to charge only one battery in a dual battery charger? You're good at that as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer:

> You can simultaneously charge and record with the HD HERO Original, HD
>   HERO2, HERO3, or HERO3+ cameras.  To do this, you can use the supplied
>   USB cable.  Use that to connect your camera to a USB wall charger or
>   auto charger that outputs 5V and 1A.  You cannot record while the
>   camera is connected to a computer.

http://gopro.com/support/articles/using-the-camera-while-charging

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* film with the camera connected to a computer. But, you need to power on the camera first and then plug the cable in. I’ve been doing this for some time. I’m using a Galaxy 10.5 tablet, with Wi-Fi, and the tablet is my viewing monitor. The camera has a battery in it, but as soon as I turn the camera on, I then I plug the USV cable in. I’m able to film, and it doesn’t go into USB mode.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

YES... Here is some UNIX scripting that will read the last LRV via wifi and display it on your computer.

```
#!/bin/sh

### Isolates LRV files from Go Pro Video files
curl -L http://10.5.5.9/videos/DCIM/100GOPRO/ | grep -wo --color -e \G.......\.L.V\< |tr -d \< > LRVfile; sleep 1

### Hold the Name of the most recent Video file and change to .MP4
NAME=$(tail -r -n1 LRVfile | sed s/LRV/MP4/g) ; 
echo $NAME 

### Prepares Full File Address to send to the browser
sed 's/^/http:\/\/10.5.5.9\/videos\/DCIM\/100GOPRO\//g' LRVfile > LRV.http

### or
#sed 's/^/http:\/\/10.5.5.9\/videos\/DCIM\/100GOPRO\//g' LRVfile



### Read the LAST file, write file, print file Name
curl $(tail -r -n1 LRV.http) > /Volumes/"Work Space"/CapturedGOPR/$NAME ; echo " "; 
echo Reading:  $(tail -r -n1 LRV.http) && echo " " && sleep 15;
rm LRVfile && rm LRV.http && exit

#tail -r LRV.http | while read F; do curl $F > /Volumes/"Work Space"/CapturedGOPR/$NAME ; echo " "; echo Reading:  $F && echo " " && exit; done;
```

Comment: So, connected with a usb cable as asked by the op ??